# jquery, add to div on input box change

Tags: jquery, append

http://jsfiddle.net/y8gA6/2/

I like to add the range to the `testDiv` as 1111-2222 without replacing the existing text inside the testDiv, how do I do that, append is continuosly appending the values on every key up, .html() replacing the existing text. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use `change` event instead ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/y8gA6/4/)):

```
$('input[name=low],input[name=high]').on("change", function(){
    //...
});
```

The `change` event happens only if content changes in the element and after you leave the element, so all content will be appended at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add span to your div after the text and `.text()` your values to it like

```
$('input[name=low],input[name=high]').on("keyup paste", function(){
var min = $("input[name=low]").val();
var max = $("input[name=high]").val();

$('#range').text(min+'-'+max);
});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/y8gA6/5/)

Or you can save your text in some variable and then just add it to your `.html()`
like it made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/y8gA6/6/)